# php unit testing problem in phpunit.xml file

Tags: php, xml, phpunit

working with php unit testing and My phpunit.xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encording="UTF-8" ?>

<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">

    <testsuits>
    
         <testsuit name="unit">
         
             <directory>tests</directory>
         
         </testsuit>
    
    </testsuits>

</phpunit>
```

but when i execute following running command `vendor/bin/phpunit` compiler got following error messages
`Could not load "C:\Users\Orukawa\Desktop\phpunittest\phpunit.xml".`
`parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected`

how could I fix this prob?

Comment: Your declaration has a typo. `encording` instead of `encoding`.

Comment: @rpm192 yes, now working fine

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `phpunit.xml`. Correct configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">

    <testsuits>
    
         <testsuit name="unit">
         
             <directory>tests</directory>
         
         </testsuit>
    
    </testsuits>

</phpunit>
```